# issues loading assembly from another project

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, iis, dll

I have a dll from some 3rd party provider.  I referenced it from my MVC project, and it all works just fine.

I decided to pull out all the code that uses that dll into a separate project. I then removed the reference of the dll from my MVC project, and instead referenced my other project that is the wrapper/abstraction of that api.

Now, I'm getting the following error while the server tries loading up:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'xxxx' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.
```

I've seen lots of questions on this site and elsewhere that deal with x64 vs x86 and other exotic-seeming scenarios, but I'm not sure that my situation applies here.  Just to be sure, I tried all possible combinations of x86/x64/any cpu on both projects and it had no effect.

What am I missing here, or what did I do wrong?

Comment: Ok, We have projects A B and C, A reference B, B reference C, On runtime, can you verify that C dll exist on the library where A is running from ? if you are not sure print to console the directory where the process is running A from and then see with your eyes that C dll is placed there

Comment: both B and C dlls exist in the directory where the process is running A from.  I don't know if this matters at all, but this is a dll that comes as a companion to another, and appears to be i18n-related.  The companion dll doesn't get copied over to the A directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [the suggestion by Zephryl](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19886086/437456), I got the following assembly binding log:

```
LOG: User = IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool
LOG: DisplayName = Laserfiche.I18n83
 (Partial)
WRN: Partial binding information was supplied for an assembly:
WRN: Assembly Name: Laserfiche.I18n83 | Domain ID: 5
WRN: A partial bind occurs when only part of the assembly display name is provided.
WRN: This might result in the binder loading an incorrect assembly.
WRN: It is recommended to provide a fully specified textual identity for the assembly,
WRN: that consists of the simple name, version, culture, and public key token.
WRN: See whitepaper http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=109270 for more information and common solutions to this issue.
```

I'm in over my head, so I just started panic-Googling and ran across [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13589619/437456) which told me to set stuff to `CopyLocal=true`.  Googling around about what that means led to a bunch of black-and-white opinions about why it's evil and/or genius to do this, so I decided it's a wash and set it to true for my dll.  This had no effect, but then I set `CopyLocal=true` for the companion dlls that came with this 3rd party tool, and then it suddenly started working!

I'm not sure what partial binding exactly means, or how to get around it, or if there's a better way, but this seemed to do the trick.  I'll follow up here if there end up being any negative side-effects of this.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is most likely due to your machine or the way you've configured IIS.  Most likely when IIS is spooling up your site, your two libraries conflict.  Try checking your application pool and take a look at the General section.  I have included an image below:

[image]

If the third party library is strictly 32-bit compiled and your server is 64-bit you will need to make sure that this options is set to true.

Comment: My Advanced settings look identical to yours (except for the name), and the dll I'm trying to reference is 64-bit, as is my server.

Just for fun, I tried referencing the 32-bit version of the dll instead, with the same result

Answer (score 1):

You might try getting more info using the assembly binding log viewer.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4(v=VS.100).aspx

See the following link for details on enabling:
[How to enable assembly bind failure logging (Fusion) in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/255669/how-to-enable-assembly-bind-failure-logging-fusion-in-net)